# dumb terminal in non-interactive docker

Tags: emacs, docker, drone.io

I have a CI script that is run in a non-interactive docker container. One of the applications I use (emacs in batch mode) expects a TTY, even though it is never going to read from it.

In interactive mode, I can pipe `/dev/tty` to the application, but in non-interactive mode the device doesn't even exist!

How can I create a fake terminal in a non-interactive docker container?

BTW, I do not have control over the CI runner (drone) which starts the script... so I cannot add `-i` or `-t`

Running `ls -R /dev` gives

```
/dev:
fd
full
fuse
kcore
mqueue
null
ptmx
pts
random
shm
stderr
stdin
stdout
tty
urandom
zero

/dev/mqueue:

/dev/pts:
ptmx

/dev/shm:
```

Comment: Can you post a reproducer?

Comment: just run any emacs batch job in any docker container, with interactive mode turned off and no `-t` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap the invocation of your script in a `script` (literally) invocation. There's a similar problem when su'ing to another user, and then accessing a screen session.

```
$ script /dev/null
$ emacs ...
$ exit
```

See also https://serverfault.com/a/116830